# The automatic Selection Change event that follows editing a cell selects the same new cell even if my Change event code defines a new destination cell

Tags: vba, excel, sorting, events

Screenupdate suppression is released and original macro ended

I have spent 3 hours on this and tracked back the Bug? to this point, but it is not logical for me what I see happening and therefore not finding an optimal cure.
Please help.

I use _SelectionChange event to store the values of cells in a global variable.
To be used as the Old value when a _Change event kicks in after modifying a cell value.

As part of the _Change triggered macro , the list values are updated all over dynamically and towards the end i trigger a Sort, to make the list ordered again.
I finish it with activating again the cell that was modified before the sort (in its NEW position)

I have tracked the value stored in oVal (selection change) and it displays the correct value all along.
However when the macro ends, automatically 1 extra selectionChange event fires (without the election truly changing) that gives a new value to oVal and messes up later calculations.

I noticed when going step by step, that the Cell in question was selected during the Sorting, but my I have purposefully Activated at the end of my macro the cell I wanted to finish on. (and the value IS updated) , however after the macro ends, the suppressed selection change of the Sorting kicks in.

**Now with visuals and code:**
Let suppose i have a list of 
Anne - 1
John - 2
Stuart - 3
Bono - 4

I select the number 1. (oVal remembers : 1)
I give a new value of 4.
Now my code compares oVal1 with nVal5 to determine the parameters of the movement and updates John to be 1, Stuart 2 , Bono3 ; and places Anne as 4.
With the help of the Sort it also sorts Anne to the end of the list.
Since the Sort selects by itself "some random" cell, i'm activating 4 manually with the help of searching for the new location of it.
oVal now remembers 4 (as it should) as the new-old value.
BUT then when the macro ended, SelectionChange kicks in and sets oVal to 2 (that was selected by the sort) - Without!!!! moving the cell selection there.
This is a problem, because if now i dont move my selection manually, but instead i give yet a new value to Ann (with a Spinner for example) the list becomes corrupted with wrong values, because of wrong oVal.

**EDIT:**
As per request i have reconstructed the issue in a small MCV test scenario.
TestScene in Excel:
[image: Test scenario]

(H11 was just chosen for a visual output to track oVal for now)

TestCode Here:

```
Option Explicit

Dim oVal As Variant

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
oVal = Target.Value
Application.EnableEvents = False
ActiveSheet.Range("H11").Value = oVal
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Application.EnableEvents = False
Range("F13").Value = 1
Range("F14").Value = 2
Range("F15").Value = 3
Range("F16").Value = 4
Call testsort
Application.EnableEvents = True
Range("F16").Activate
End Sub

Sub testsort()
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table2").Sort.SortFields.Clear
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table2").Sort.SortFields.Add _
        Key:=Range("Table2[[#All],[c]]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:= _
        xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet3").ListObjects("Table2").Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
End Sub
```

**What you will see happen here, is that oVal takes the value of 5 at the end of my code, and then out of the blue Change kicks in again, and changes the val to 2.**

### **the full code:**  (-removed-)

**EDIT 2** : The workaround:
I have tested a workaround after understanding the nature of the problem better. See below

---

**Solution:**

```
Option Explicit

Dim oVal As Variant
Dim cameFromChange As Boolean

Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If cameFromChange = False Then
    oVal = Target.Value
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    ActiveSheet.Range("H11").Value = oVal
    Application.EnableEvents = True
Else
    cameFromChange = False

    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Range("F13").Value = 1
    Range("F14").Value = 2
    Range("F15").Value = 3
    Range("F16").Value = 4
    Call testsort
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Range("F16").Activate
End If


End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
cameFromChange = True

End Sub
```

Comment: It would be much more helpful if you posted an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) instead.

Comment: I have submitted a test scenario as you requested.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the `selection_change` that occurs after you submit the value in the cell.

There is a setting in Excel (Options - Advanced - After pressing Enter move selection) that controls where the cursor will go after an edit, and it will cause a `selection_change`. It will do so even if you untick the option to move the cursor - then it will raise `selection_change` on the edited cell itself.

What makes it confusing is the fact that the events happen in the following order:

- You press enter to commit your edit
- The selection updates (the cursor moves on the screen, the `Selection` property updates)
- `Worksheet_Change` fires
- `Selection_Change` fires

I'm sure there were reasons to make it in this order (and not in the order of the change event, then move the cursor, then the selection event), but anyway you will have to accommodate your code to the fact that there is always a `Selection_Change` associated with any user-induced cell edit, and that it always fires after the `Worksheet_Change` returns (and does not fire at all if the Change event was triggered by assigning a cell's `Value` programmatically).

Comment: Thank you, this explains (and messes up) everything :) 
It would be an acceptable feature if there was a parameter somewhere that we could change programatically.

My best idea to work around this is to save also the NewValue in some variable for later and let the extra SelectionChange happen at the very beginning.
When that is finished, turn off Events and run the rest of the ChangeEvent's code within the SelectionChange's code. (with the help of a 3rd variable that is set to monitor the nature of the SC call.

Cheers

Comment: The complaint part more precisely:  The problem is NOT that the SelectionChange is "Flagged" to happen after the Change, The problem is that the "Flag" cannot be overwritten by another SC that happens within the Change's code. I have tried to overwrite it by setting the new selection manually, but excel just doesn't care and still run the original event unchanged.